# php download excel file

Tags: php, excel, apache, http-headers

I write php code downloading excel file, when I test it on my localhost everything fine, the file can be open, however when I go to my server and I test the code, the file is no more readable. Here is my code

```
$file = basename($path);

if(file_exists($path)){

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
        header("Content-Type:  application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
        readfile($path);
      exit;
}
```

for the envir , I use PHP Version 7.2.19 in local and 7.0.33 in my server, and I try all the content-type that i found but no one work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ob_clean();
```

put that code before all header declaration.